# Postgres: sql query by filter date range

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, pgadmin, datefilter

I have table Test which including date column potatoeDate. I want to take records by querying by date from this column. And when I querying by date from **Y**.AA.AAAA to **X**.AA.AAAA, always got records from **Y**.AA.AAAA to **(X-1)**.AA.AAA. For example, i searching from 01.10.2017 to 30.10.2017, but I got records from range 01-29.10.2017.

I try everything what I know, event subqueries but nothing helped.
My attempts:

```
    Select n1.potatoeDate 
    FROM (SELECT potatoeDate from test WHERE  potatoeDate > '2017/05/07'::date) n1
    WHERE  n1.potatoeDate <= '2017/05/08'::date;

    select * 
    from test
    where potatoeDate between '2017/05/07' and '2017/05/08'

    SELECT potatoeDate from test
    where
    potatoeDate >= '2017/05/07' AND
    potatoeDate <= '2017/05/08'

--little hack
    SELECT potatoeDate from test
    WHERE  
    potatoeDate >= '2017/05/07'::date
    AND 
    potatoeDate <= ('2017/05/08'::date)+1;
```

Only the last little hack query working. :|

Can someone help me? :)

Comment: Isn't `potatoeDate` is of type `timestamp`? That would explain the behaviour

Comment: Yes is it. Can You explain reason?

Comment: See my answer. If it's not quite clear, just let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that `potatoeDate` is of type `timestamp`.

When you compare `date` with `timestamp` the `timestamp` is larger (is later in time) if it has even just one second. Try to cast a `date` to `timestamp` and see that it has `00:00:00` in time field. So `timestamp` with time different than `00:00:00` would be larger.

Comment: Indeed, you are right! The only solution is add whole timestamp to query with interesting range of hours? You know how to solve it in other way/s?

I mean, for example:  
_where potatoeDate between '2017/05/07'::timestamp and '2017/05/08 23:59:59'_

Comment: If you are just interested in limiting range in days then I suggest adding 1 day to the upper limit (just as you did in the last example: `potatoeDate < ('2017/05/08'::date)+1;`), or, more elegant `+ INTERVAL '1 day'`.

Answer (score 2):

I found solution(information from @Adam helped). :)

In this situation its necessary to cast column name in where clause to ***date*** type. When its changed, all queries return expected results.

Example :

```
select * 
from test
where potatoeDate::date between '2017/05/07' and '2017/05/08'

SELECT potatoeDate from test
where
potatoeDate::date >= '2017/05/07' AND
potatoeDate::date <= '2017/05/08'
```

Comment: Well, it's easy to write, but it's more expensive to evaluate by database. I wouldn't do that...

Comment: It is more expensive, because DB must cast all records to date format, ook understood, again You are right. 
So, the simple concatenation is more effective in this situation.